# Highlight a row when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-sheets, getmethod

I would like to color in red the rows where between column F and K there is no value ' ', or the value KO.

I managed to find a script where I can delete the lines where these conditions are met, but not to color them:

```
   function deleteRows()
   {
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
     let numRows = rows.getNumRows();
     var values ​​= rows.getValues();
 
     var rowsDeleted = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++)
     {
       var row = values[i];
       if (row[5] == 'KO' || row[5] == '')
       if (row[6] == 'KO' || row[6] == '')
       if (row[7] == 'KO' || row[7] == '')
       if (row[8] == 'KO' || row[8] == '')
       if (row[9] == 'KO' || row[9] == '')
       if (row[10] == 'KO' || row[10] == '')
       {
         sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
         rowsDeleted++;
       }
     }
   }
```

could you help me on this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to set the background color of rows where the columns "F" to "K" are empty or the columns "F" to "K" don't include a value of "KO".

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var colorAr = Array(lastColumn).fill("red");
  var nullAr = Array(lastColumn).fill(null);
  var range = sheet.getRange("F2:K" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getValues().map(r => (r.join("") == "" || r.includes("KO")) ? colorAr : nullAr);
  range.offset(0, -5, values.length, values[0].length).setBackgrounds(values);
}
```

- In order to set the background color, `setBackgrounds(color)` is used.

  - In this sample, the background color is changed to "red" color. Please modify this for your actual situation.
- I thought that in your situation, when the values are retrieved from the columns "F" to "K" and the retrieved values are checked with the condition, the script might be a bit simple.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)

Comment: @yml Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.